# mat card is not fitting with entire page

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using Angular Material, Bootstrap.

I am trying to show the mat-card which should fit for all screen.

But I am seeing an empty spaces right side of the card

For some screen resolution it is fitting properly. Can anyone suggest what I need to here

StacKblitz URL: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-responsive?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Below attached the screen shot of empty space

[image]

Mobile View is in below screen shot
[image]

Working fine with below screen resolution
[image]

Comment: Why do you have a fixed width of 350px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap Grid utility, and specify number of columns for each `mat-card`. Also you can specify how you want it to be displayed on what screen size.
For example, to display 4 cards in one row on big screens, 3 on medium, and 2 on small, you can do this:

```
class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6"
```

Here is the updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-responsive-yvkfxc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex layout.
add mat cards between flex layout  tags.

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
  <div fxFlex="25%" *ngFor="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here fxFlex = "25%" means in one row it includes 4 mat cards..